# fetch all data from database having same name

Tags: mysqli

I have a web page to display images with its name. When I click on the name the respective image visible. when I add additional images with the same name in the database, only single name display and when I click on the name all images with that name should visible.  my table looks like,

```
name  | image
---------------
blue  | blue.jpg
blue  | blue1.jpg
red   | red.jpg
```

in the front page only single names should display and when I click blue on the web page all images with blue should display. Please help me what would be the query for fetching like that. I use the query

```
select name image from table1 where name='blue' group by name
```

But when using this only single name and single image appears. Please help me

Comment: Why do you have a `group by` in your query?

Comment: I need to display name only once. When using group by it working. but only single image is displaying

Comment: What you display is up to your frontend code. What you retrieve from the database is up to your SQL. If you group by foo, you will only get back one line per distinct foo. That's what group by means.

Comment: What would be my front-end code to display all images with the single name? I use PHP and MySQLi

Answer (score -1):

It's showing only one name because you are filtering by a single name in the `where` clause. Remove it and also, it's better to group by all fields selected:

```
select name, image from table1 group by name, image
```